# Validate a kerberos service token with keytab

Tags: kerberos

A similar question has been asked before on this forum, but the accepted answer hasn't been helpful to me. My server has a Kerberos keytab file that I'd like to use to validate a service ticket sent by a client.

Following Sun's documentation and sample code scattered elsewhere this is what I currently have:

1. Client requests a service ticket from the KDC for MYSPN
2. Client sends the file to the Service Server to request access to the service.
3. Server grants access after validating service ticket with keytab for MYSPN it already has.

I'm having trouble getting #3 to work. The specific error I get is:

```
GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new ACCEPT credentials failed!)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential.getInstance(Krb5AcceptCredential.java:100)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:128)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:200)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:319)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
    at cms.gssapi.Server$1.run(Server.java:188)
    at cms.gssapi.Server$1.run(Server.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:357)
    at cms.gssapi.Server.acceptSecurityContext(Server.java:182)
    at cms.gssapi.Server.main(Server.java:59)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Princpal Name for authentication 
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Krb5LoginModule.java:750)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:646)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:559)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$5.run(LoginContext.java:721)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$5.run(LoginContext.java:719)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokeCreatorPriv(LoginContext.java:718)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:590)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSUtil.login(GSSUtil.java:264)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util.getKeys(Krb5Util.java:202)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential$1.run(Krb5AcceptCredential.java:95)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential$1.run(Krb5AcceptCredential.java:93)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential.getInstance(Krb5AcceptCredential.java:92)
    ... 11 more
```

This is a snippet of the server code that tries to validate the client's service ticket using keytab:

```
 public static void main( String[] args) {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.load( new FileInputStream( "server.properties"));
      System.setProperty( "sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
      System.setProperty( "java.security.krb5.realm", props.getProperty( "realm"));
      System.setProperty( "java.security.krb5.kdc", props.getProperty( "kdc"));
      System.setProperty( "java.security.auth.login.config", "./jaas.conf");
      System.setProperty( "javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
      krb5Oid = new Oid( "1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
      Server server = new Server();
      server.login();
      byte serviceTicket[] = readClientTicketFromFile();
      String clientName = server.acceptSecurityContext(serviceTicket);
  }

  private static byte[] readClientTicketFromFile() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "serviceticket.token"));
    String str;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
       buffer.append( str + "\n");
    }
    in.close();
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    return decoder.decodeBuffer( buffer.toString());
  }

  private static Oid krb5Oid;

  private Subject login() throws LoginException {
    LoginContext loginCtx = null;
    loginCtx = new LoginContext( "Server", new LoginCallbackHandler(null,null));   
    System.out.println("Attempting to do Login...");
    loginCtx.login();
    Subject ret_sub = loginCtx.getSubject();
     return ret_sub;
  }


  private String acceptSecurityContext( final byte[] serviceTicket) 
      throws GSSException {
    krb5Oid = new Oid( "1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
    return Subject.doAs( subject, new PrivilegedAction<String>() {
      public String run() {
        try {
          GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
          GSSContext context = manager.createContext( (GSSCredential) null);
          context.acceptSecContext( serviceTicket, 0, serviceTicket.length);
          return context.getSrcName().toString();
        }
        catch ( Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return null;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is my server.properties

```
realm=MYREALM
kdc=192.168.1.1
```

and jaas.conf file

```
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useTicketCache=false
  useKeyTab=false
  storeKey=false
  isInitiator=true
  debug=true
  ;
};

Server {
     com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
     useKeyTab=true 
     storeKey=true 
     doNotPrompt=true
     isInitiator=false
     keyTab="/etc/krb5.keytab"
     principal="MYSPN/host.domain.com@MYREALM"
     debug=true
     ;
};
```

I'm sure the service ticket is valid because the server can authenticate if I provide password for the service account, but I want to use a keytab file instead of password.